# filepath.Abs() does not provide subdirectory in result

Tags: go, path

I have directory like:

```
myproject/
├─ data/
│  ├─ test.csv
├─ go.mod
├─ main.go
```

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {

    fullPath := `C:\myproject\data\test.csv`
    f, err := os.Open(fullPath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    fileInfo, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // get full file path
    filePath, err := filepath.Abs(fileInfo.Name())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(filePath)
}
```

However, `filepath.Abs(fileInfo.Name())` gives me `C:\myproject\test.csv`. instead of what I would desire `C:\myproject\data\test.csv`

IIUC, `fileInfo.Name()` should give me the same path as what was fed into `os.Open()`, so why wouldn't `filepath.Abs()` recognize the directory that the file is in? `filepath.Dir(fileInfo.Name())` gives me `.` as well... which I would expect to be `C:\myproject\data\`.

I am running my go file from within `myproject` directory.

`go version 1.19.3 windows/amd64`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fileInfo.Name()` returns just the base name of the file, [as documented](https://pkg.go.dev/io/fs#FileInfo), with no path info. So you're passing just a raw filename to `filepath.Abs`. As such, the function is doing [exactly what the documentation says it will do](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Abs):

> If the path is not absolute it will be joined with the current working directory to turn it into an absolute path.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I would need to create a separate call to ```filepath.Dir(fullPath)``` to get the base path and ```filepath.Join()``` them together to construct the original filepath. Seems that ```fileInfo.Name()``` doesn't serve much purpose here then, as I could just construct from the raw ```fullPath``` string. My goal is to take the original base file path as a prefix for files that I will be writing as chunks from this single file.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. You already know the absolute path--that was your input. So it's hard to advise the best approach.

Comment: Yeah.. Sorry. the issue is that I am using a ```*os.File``` in the actual code which is why I wanted to be able to construct the full absolute path from the ```*os.File``` object by using ```.Stat()```. But it doesn't appear obvious on how to get the full absolute path from just the ```*os.File``` object

Comment: You can't get the absolute path from a `*os.File` object. In fact, the concept is ambiguous. There might be 0, 1, or many, filename references to an open *os.File object. If you open the file, then delete it, then there is no path to it. Or if you have multiple links to the file, then there could be many.  You'll need to consider a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I will have to perhaps maintain a struct with the full path information alongside the ```*os.File``` object.

Comment: @Coldchain9 you might consider using [`os.File.Name()`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Name) which returns the name of the file "as presented to Open".  Assuming the you haven't changed the working directory, `filepath.Abs(f.Name())` should give you the absolute path of the file that was opened as it was specified to open, even if that string is (for some reason) not available to you.

Comment: @erik258 I did not know that was an option! Thank you!

Comment: I didn't either until I went looking at the documentation.  I can't overstate the value of reading the excellent documentation that comes along with the standard go library.  Every function is there, and typically quite well explained.  You can learn all sorts of stuff!